# How to encode JSON data produced by jackson?

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

The data returned by the json contains accented letters , so I want to encode them. Here is how the json is produced :

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
...
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajaxDataTableListUsers", produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public String ajaxList(@RequestParam int draw, @RequestParam int start, @RequestParam int length, 
                               @RequestParam("search[value]") String search, @RequestParam("order[0][column]") int triIdx, @RequestParam("order[0][dir]") String ordreTri) 
    throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

        List<Object[]> utilisateursDataTable = utilisateurDao.list(start, length, search, triIdx, ordreTri);
        List<Utilisateur> utilisateursAll = utilisateurDao.list();
        DataTablesTO<Object[]> dt = new DataTablesTO<Object[]>();
        dt.setData(utilisateursDataTable);
        dt.setDraw(draw);
        if (search == null || search.equals("")) {
            dt.setRecordsTotal(utilisateursAll.size());
            dt.setRecordsFiltered(utilisateursAll.size());
        }
        else {
            dt.setRecordsTotal(utilisateursDataTable.size());
            dt.setRecordsFiltered(utilisateurDao.nbUtilisateurTotalFiltered(search));
        }

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        return mapper.writeValueAsString(dt); // how to encode the data here ?

    }
```

I debugged the string returned and it contains the desired data with accented letters. The problem is when the data is represented in DataTable then the accented letters are not represented ! So how to encode the json data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set character encoding in @RequestMapping like below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajaxDataTableListUsers", produces = {"application/json; charset=UTF-8"})
```